# Changed framework version results in: Could not load file or assembly PresentationFramework?

Tags: .net, wpf, frameworks

I am working on WPF application, which was first targeted to 3.0 framework. When I tried to make it work on 4.0, I got following Exception.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException was
>   unhandled Message: Could not load file
>   or assembly 'PresentationFramework,
>   Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.

If I compile application using .Net 4.0 it is working fine. But 3.0 exes are not working with 4.0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove the DLL reference to the PresentationFramework in your Visual Studio project, then retarget your application framework in the Project Properties, and then add PresentationFramework reference again.

Comment: Should note, would be targeting/adding *.NET 4.0* references when all is said and done.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the PresentationFramework.Aero.dll was not present on the other system even though the expected version of .NET Framework was installed, but I didn't investigate too much.

Instead, in my solution, under References, I found that reference, and in the Properties of the reference, I changed Copy Local to True.  This included the dll with my project output, and as a result, the other system was able to find it when the program ran.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: I don't think it is correct to use copy local, because parts of the framework probably should not be distributed with the application. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8185946/3195477

Comment: Setting Copy Local to True (for PresentationFramework.Aero) worked for me. Great.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error after copy-pasting a TextBox in XAML which held an event trigger. Removing this from the newly copied TextBox resolved my issue.

I realize that this probably describes a very specific instance of the Exception, but I hope that it may help others resolve their problem.